# Accessing child object of json

Tags: json

I have this json object:

```
var jst =   {"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.uzti.com"},{"email":"harshit.raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.url.com"}]}
```

Whenever I do jst.cust[0].email. Javascript shows me undefined

More detailed code:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type:'GET',
            url:'/ajax_res.php',
            data:"q="+id,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

                var jst = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(jst);
                console.log(jst.cust[0].email);

                /*$.each(json.cust, function(index, element) {
                    console.log(element.email); 
                });*/

                //alert(json[0]);
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: How are you processing it? show more codes where you try to access it parse it. When i access it works fine `st.cust[0].email`

Comment: I have provided the whole code

Comment: wrap json under quotes as i have mentioned in answer

Answer (score 1):

Following `string/json` needs to be enclosed by quotes

Change this to

```
var jst =   {"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.uzti.com"},{"email":"harshit.raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.url.com"}]}
```

this

```
var jst =   '{"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.uzti.com"},{"email":"harshit.raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.url.com"}]}';
```

**Here is working example**

```js
 var jst =   '{"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.uzti.com"},{"email":"harshit.raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.url.com"}]}';

var jst = JSON.parse(jst);
alert(jst.cust[0].email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `debugger;`

use `typeof` function to determine whether your data is `object` or `string`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/ajax_res.php',
  data: "q=" + id,
  success: function(data) {
    debugger;
------^    
    var jst = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(jst.cust[0].email);

  }
});
```

then check that you're getting right thing what You're expecting.

Then in your `console` try to access that `data`.

```
var test = JSON.parse('{"cust":[{"email":"harsht283raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.uzti.com"},{"email":"harshit.raj@jumia.com", "url":"www.url.com"}]}');

test.cust[0].email
o/p - "harsht283raj@jumia.com"
```

You're doing right way. Just recheck your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse it using `JSON.pars`e. You can simply access the JavaScript object properties of the json data received.

```
 success: function(data){
   alert(data.cust[0].email);
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tucikeneja/edit?html,js,output) is a working sample

If you want to access each item in the cust array,

```
if(data.cust)
{
   $.each(data.cust,function(indx,item){    
         alert(item.email);        
   });
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tucikeneja/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample for that.